# How do I set multi-value HTTP headers, like Content-Security-Policy?

Tags: go, http-headers, content-security-policy

I'm trying to set the Content-Security-Policy header on a http.ResponseWriter object. This is a header with multiple values. My problem is that all the methods for [http.Header](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Header) take a single key and a single value. For example, the [Set() method](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Header.Set) looks like this:

```
func (h Header) Set(key, value string)
```

There's no method for assigning a *slice* of values to a header field. I want a header that looks like this.

```
header := http.Header{
    "Content-Type": {"text/html; charset=UTF-8"},
    "Content-Security-Policy": {"default-src 'self'", "font-src themes.googleusercontent.com", "frame-src 'none'", "style-src 'self' fonts.googleapis.com"},
}
```

This will create the header, but I don't know how to associate it with the http.ResponseWriter object. Furthermore, if I were somehow able to replace the ResponseWriter's header with the header above, would I have to set the Content-Length field by hand?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand the problem, however `Content-Security-Policy` expects one header that contains a list separated by `;`.

If you want to use a slice you can always use something like this:

```
csp := []string{"default-src: 'self'", "font-src: 'fonts.googleapis.com'", "frame-src: 'none'"}
header := http.Header{
    "Content-Type": {"text/html; charset=UTF-8"},
}
header.Set("Content-Security-Policy", strings.Join(csp, "; "))
```

Also if you want to send the header multiple times with different values (like you originally intended, I think), you can use [`header.Add`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Header.Add).

> Add adds the key, value pair to the header. **It appends** to any existing values associated with key.

If you want to use that in your http handler, get the header with [ResponseWriter.Header()](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ResponseWriter):

```
func Handler(rw http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    header := rw.Header()
    csp := []string{"default-src: 'self'", "font-src: 'fonts.googleapis.com'", "frame-src: 'none'"}

    header.Set("Content-Type": "text/html; charset=UTF-8")
    header.Set("Content-Security-Policy", strings.Join(csp, "; "))
    rw.WriteHeader(200) //or write anything really
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I was confused by the fact that http.Header is a map[string][]string. That means Set() must be splitting the single string on the semicolon. I'm slapping my head for not considering that.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't address CSP directly (yet), but it does cover "the other 4" security headers

http://godoc.org/github.com/kr/secureheader

Answer (score 0):

I  created a middleware to set the CSP header.

```
package main

import (
    "gorila-mux/ctrls"
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gorilla/context"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

func main() {
    r := mux.NewRouter()

    r.HandleFunc("/", ctrls.HomeHandler)
    r.PathPrefix("/public/").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/public/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("public/"))))
    http.Handle("/", r)
    r.Use(setCSPHeaders)
    log.Print("Project is serving on port 7000 : http://localhost:7000")
    http.ListenAndServe(":7000", context.ClearHandler(http.DefaultServeMux))

}


func setCSPHeaders(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        //  w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
        w.Header().Set("Content-Security-Policy", "default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'; object-src 'self';style-src 'self' img-src 'self'; media-src 'self'; frame-ancestors 'self'; frame-src 'self'; connect-src 'self'")
        next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}
```